# Ошибка подключения библиотеки через CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

Вопрос вроде бы как банальный, но решить не могу.

Нужно подключить ceres solver к проекту c++. CMakeList выглядит так

```
...
find_package(Ceres REQUIRED)
...
target_link_libraries(library ${CERES_LIBRARIES})
...
```

Но CMake выдаёт такую ошибку

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresTargets.cmake:80 (message):
  The imported target "Ceres::ceres" references the file

     "/usr/local/lib/libceres.a"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained

     "/usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresTargets.cmake"

  but not all the files it references.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresConfig.cmake:272 (include)
  library/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

Я поискал и понял, что `libceres.a` лежить в   `"/usr/lib/libceres.a"`, а `CeresTargets.cmake` - в  `"/usr/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresTargets.cmake"`

Как мне теперь указать путь в CMakeList, что бы поиск был не в `/usr/local/lib/`, а в `/usr/lib/`?

Comment: `CeresTargets.cmake` судя по сообщению, лежит в `/usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresTargets.cmake`. А `libceres.a` - должен быть в `/usr/local/lib/`. ¿Вы случаем не выполняли каких-либо действий, нарушающих порядок установки пакетов? типа `sudo make install` ¿Откуда вы берете эту самую libceres?

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо за наводку. Действительно, был конфликт в версиях. `CeresTargets.cmake` подтягивался из `/usr/local/lib/cmake/Ceres/CeresTargets.cmake`. Хотя основная версия нахордится в `/usr/lib/`